# "Сніговик" та "Снігова баба" який з варіантів правильний?

Tags: вживання-слів

В усній мові використовуються обидва варіанти. В СУМ  є лише один варіант ***[снігова баба](http://sum.in.ua/s/baba)***, у Вікіпедії ***[сніговик](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA)*** з заначенням в дужках *снігова баба*. Також знайшла, що на Русі називали *снігова баба*, тоді як в європейських країнах *сніговик*, але [сайт](http://korali.info/obryadi/snigova-baba-chi-snigovik.html) викликає сумніви в достовірності інформації.
Чи можна використовувати обидва варіанти на письмі?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Аналіз

Згаданий Вами «Словник української мови» в 11 томах 1970-х, хоча й не містить безпосередньо статті «сніговик», але згадує це слово в цитатах до інших статей:

- > [**КАЧА́ТИ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/kachaty) <…> *Сніг качали та ліпили, хто як міг і хто як звик, і невдовзі виріс білий величезний сніговик* (Наталя Забіла, У.. світ, 1960, 21). <…>

  (Це слово згадується ще в двох інших статтях, але там воно не цитується безпосередньо, а зазначене як пропущене слово: «іде [сніговик]», «із вуглинок [у сніговика]» — крім того ті цитати теж належать перу Наталі Забіли.)

Сучасний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах 2010-х років ще не відкрив доступ до томів на літери *Л*–*Я*, але він теж згадує слово «сніговик» у цитатах:

- > [**ГОП-КОМПА́НІЯ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=163000&page=669) <…> *Ніхто не помічає, що, примруживши одне своє око-вуглинку, сніговик обводить поглядом усю гоп-компанію* (В. Нестайко).

  (Є й інша цитата, але вона згадує сніговик зовсім у іншому значенні — як одну із колишніх народних назв місяця січень.)

Пошук у Google Книгах не знаходить вжитків слова «сніговик» раніше 1947 року — окрім ландшафтного значення («Вісник ботаніки» 1930, «Геологічний журнал» 1935). Причому [перша згадка 1947 року](//books.google.com/books?id=T-wSAAAAIAAJ&q=%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA) посилається на назву оповідання тієї самої Наталі Забіли.

Пошук серед художньої прози у [корпусі текстів MOVA.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) теж не знаходить вжитків до 1950. З 1960-х лідує за кількістю вжитків Всеволод Нестайко; також поодиноко вживали Сапожников Леонід (1974), Оксана Іваненко (1986), Ірен Роздобудько (2001), Олександр Дерманський (2006), Лариса Денисенко (2007), Климчук Віталій (2011), Артур Сіренко (2012), Ірина Савка (2013), Надія Гуменюк (2014).

Пошук серед [словників на R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) теж не знаходить траплянь до 1950-х. Перша згадка — в «Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів» І. О. Виргана та М. М. Пилинської 1959 року: «Баба. <…> ♢ Снежная (снеговая) баба – [Снігова] баба; сніговий дід; сніговик».

Орфографічний словник [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) УМІФ НАНУ 2008 року містить слово «сніговик».

[«Етимологічний словник української мови»](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) в 7 томах містить статтю «сніговик», але із зовсім іншим значенням — варіант назви для комахи [льодовичник](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0).

## Висновки

Аналіз може помилятися, адже я проводив пошук серед дуже обмеженого обсягу інформації — але, здається, використання слова «сніговик» (у значенні снігової баби) не було притаманне українцям історично.

Але з іншого боку, по-моєму, слово вже увійшло в мову. Окрім впливу російської і поколінь, що виросли на творах Всеволода Нестайка, мені вбачається те, що слово доволі коротке і містке, але при цьому не таке багатозначне як «баба».

<sub>Поза темою: «Українсько-англійський словник» К. Андрусишина і Я. Крета 1955 року у ролі одного з еквівалентів англійського «[snowman](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=snowman&dicts=8&filter_lines=on)» наводить слово «зимован», але практичних ужитків цього слова я не бачу.</sub>